# Cant send AXIOS request from react test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I hope someone can give me a hint with the following problem.
I am currently working on the frontend for a REST API. I would like to test if I can submit a POST request.

Using the *npm test* command, the test runs and shows a green tick for this test function. However, no POST request is sent and thus no entry is written to the database.

The function createObject(json) is called correctly during the test and the JSON string passed is also correct. Unfortunately the AXIOS POST method is not called.

When I click on "Post Object" via the browser the AXIOS method is called and an object is created in the database.

**PostClient.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const options = {
    headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    } };

export class PostClient {

        // This function is called by the test, but the Axios command is not.
        static createObject(json) {

        const response = axios.post('http://localhost:8080/object/create/', JSON.stringify(json), options)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                return response;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
            return response;
    }  

}
```

**App.test.js**

```
describe('Test', function(){
   
  let id;         

  it('addObject()', function () {
    
    const response = PostClient.createObject(objectJSON);
    this.id = response.id;

    expect(response.status == 200);

  });
});
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>createObject</h2>
        <div className="createObject">
          <button onClick={() => PostClient.createObject(objectJSON)}>Post Object</button>
        </div>
       ...
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve sounds like a test smell - your test shouldn't depend on network conditions or API endpoint reachability (otherwise, it will be flaky). You should mock axios and test whether appropriate methods are called.

Comment: How can I test if the method "PostClient.createObject(objectJSON)" is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: read the comment by Yevgen Gorbunkov :)

Second: `axios.post()` method returns a Promise - you are returning that *promise* instead of returning the result of your request.

My advice is to review how promises work; [MDN has a nice article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - and maybe brush up on asynchronous code in general.

The quick and dirty solution might be to turn your function into an async function and use async/await:

```
static async createObject(json) {
    // Note: this might throw an error; try...catch is a good idea
    const response = await axios.post(url, payload, options);
    return response.data;
}
```

Comment: And just to be complete with my answer: your test would need to take the async nature of createObject into concideration too - because now createObject returns a Promise as well!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain how the test class would look like?